# How to get Minimum value in list of charecters

Tags: java

here is my doubht 
List chars=new ArrayList();

the above list contained values are [A,A,B,B,C,D,E];

i want to get A as output because this is minimum value according to ascii.
how to get this value in java.

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: String artrasoDiao="A;A;A;A;C;C;D";
  String [] diario=artrasoDiao.split(";");
  //List<Charecter> 
  List<Character> artasoList=new ArrayList<Character>();
  
  List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
  
  for (String atrasoDiarios: diario) {
   
      System.out.println("atraso daioro of customer "+atrasoDiarios);
      artasoList.add(atrasoDiarios.charAt(0));
  }
  char cutmCr = '\0';
  for(Character chr:artasoList){
   if(chr<cutmCr){
    cutmCr=chr;
   }
  }

Comment: here i am considering the final result assign to cutmCr variable

Comment: Please update your question with the code your just mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This below code block would help you.

```
List<Character> arr = new ArrayList<Character>();
        arr.add('B'); arr.add('H');
        arr.add('C'); arr.add('R');
        arr.add('D'); arr.add('E');
        arr.add('Z'); arr.add('O');
        char res = 'z';
        for (Character charat : arr) {
            if (charat <= res) {
                res = charat;
            }
        }
```